# object with network identity doesn't turn on with host, but turns on with host/play

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, mirror

anyone know why? if I run host/play it works just fine and functions, but I go for host on a remote server and play when I try to use the functionality I get this error Spawned object not found when handling Command message [netId=0]

I don't know why this isn't turning on when I connect to the server.

Comment: this is a duplicate of your question [Spawned object not found when handling Command message \[netId=0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77381008/spawned-object-not-found-when-handling-command-message-netid-0)

Comment: I was actually able to solve this by using force shown on the network identity